# Can we create a new tablespace on external drive(USB) if yes then how in windows?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-11

Can we create a new tablespace on an external drive if yes then how in windows?
I am working on Postgresql11 and I have to store data by tablespace on the external drive. I have created tablespace on the external drive, but I am not able to create a new database.
I am getting this error.
ERROR:  could not create directory "pg_tblspc/30222/PG_11_201809051/18650": Invalid argument
SQL state: XX000
So, How to solve this error.

Comment: What is the file system on the external drive? Are you attaching it via CIFS? How exactly did you create the tablespace? Are you aware that you cannot detach the external drive if you want the database to stay functional?

Comment: What is in the `pg_tblspc` subdirectory of the PostgreSQL data directory? Are you able to create the directory in the error message from the command line?

Comment: Hi, Laurenz my external drive- (USB Pendrive) and File system - NTFS. First I converted to advanced sharing properties of PenDrive and made it shareable. After that, creating tablespace by executing this SQL statement
  CREATE TABLESPACE dw_archive_pendrive
  OWNER postgres
  LOCATION E'//DESKTOP-HRES23M//dw_archive_drive//dw_archive_drive';     Then there is an error on executing this SQL Statement to create a new database.
  create database test_pendrive tablespace dw_archive_pendrive;   So, please suggest to me how to resolve this error.

Comment: Answer my questions.

Comment: This error is coming when I create the database
  ERROR:  Could not create directory "pg_tblspc/30249/PG_11_201809051/31937": Invalid argument
SQL state: XX000

Comment: pg _tblspc has 3 folders - 16397, 18615, 30249. When I open the 30249 folder, an error occurs "The filename, directory name or volume label syntax is incorrect"

Comment: If you can reproduce the error outside the database, it is an error of the operating system or file system. Find someone who knows about Windows.

Comment: I am able to access tablespace on external drive after doing these steps 1. creating the tablespace via SQL statement 2. Checked its oid via SQL statement select oid,* from pg_tablespace; 3. After this went to pg_tblspc and delete that folder and again create the folder with same oid via mklink  4. Then create the new folder  "PG_11_201809051" inside the '..pg_tblspc\30249'. After doing this, a new database was created in that tablespace and the table was also created.  But these steps are not right. My requirement is to execute only step 1 tablespace SQL statement,then access that tablespace.

Comment: Try both ways, the failure and your workaround, and search for differences in the result. Once you spot these differences, you are one step further.

Comment: Hello Anyone checks this question and give a suggestion. 1. Can we make tablespace on the external drive. @Juan Carlos Oropeza